# Anyone have the book named as Jaati Vilas by Mahirishi Marichi?

Tags: book-recommendation, caste

Anyone have the access to the book named as Jaati Vilas by Mahirishi Marichi. Or Maybe it is written by some other author ?
But the name of the book is the same - Jaati Vilas. It is in Sanskrit.

From where can I find it ?